# How to convert this kind of structure from API into a python Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

i have this result from an API but i am not be able to convert this structure into a python pandas Dataframe.

**Response from API**

response = {'lists': [{'id': '0d4348d3a7', 'name': 'list one'}, {'id': '5e3e22ae7b', 'name': 'list two'}], 'total_items': 2}

**Try one**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(response)
print(df)
                                                   lists  total_items
    0  {'id': '0d4348d3a7', 'name': 'list one'            2
    1  {'id': '5e3e22ae7b', 'name': 'list two...          2
```

No exactly what i want.

**Try two**

```
df = json.loads(response)
print(df)

Raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

Thanks

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you show that you have tried to solve the problem. To get you started, you may find [this](https://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html) tutorial interesting.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, i've tried but with no luck, sorry for not post some code examples. I am triying with you references.

Comment: How do you get from your example to a list of dictionaries as shown in `sales = ...`? What's `response["lists"]`?

Ignore the answers talking about `json`. Your data structure is already in Python, so that's not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite close, just don't pass the entire response json by itself, but only the value you require:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> response = {'lists': [{'id': '0d4348d3a7', 'name': 'list one'}, {'id': '5e3e22ae7b', 'name': 'list two'}], 'total_items': 2}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(response["lists"])
>>> df
           id      name
0  0d4348d3a7  list one
1  5e3e22ae7b  list two
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by Dataframe? Do you mean a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)?

You API Response looks like a JSON to me, hence `json` should do your job:

```
import json
response = "{'lists': [{'id': '0d4348d3a7', 'name': 'list one'}, {'id': '5e3e22ae7b', 'name': 'list two'}], 'total_items': 2}"
dataframe = json.loads(response)
```

loads stands for load from string, check the [python package description](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html) for more methods and details.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, it trhows an error raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: Hey Vince, did you miss surrounding the JSON string with parantheses?

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use the `json` library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
a = json.loads('{"lists": [{"id": "0d4348d3a7", "name": "list one"}, {"id": "5e3e22ae7b", "name": "list two"}], "total_items": 2}')
print(a['lists'])
```

However, your API response should be JSON-formatted if you use the JSON decoder, otherwise you'll raise a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError` exception. What you posted is not JSON and will raise this exception: I edited your response text to get this to decode.

If you need a pandas dataframe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import pandas as pd
a = json.loads('{"lists": [{"id": "0d4348d3a7", "name": "list one"}, {"id": "5e3e22ae7b", "name": "list two"}], "total_items": 2}')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a['lists'])
print(df)
'''
           id      name
0  0d4348d3a7  list one
1  5e3e22ae7b  list two
'''
```